# Python: Adjusting Text Size in a Button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, text-size

I'm making a simple GUI with TKinter. I use this code to create a button with some text labelling it:

```
myButton_multiply = Button(root, text="*", padx=44, pady=20, bg="#7FFFD4", fg="green", command=button_multiply)
myButton_multiply.grid(row=5, column=0)
```

The text was smaller than I wanted, so I tried changing the size of the text by using `font()`. However, when I do this, the button's size changes as well.
How can I resize the text label while leaving the button the same size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the edit in order to understand how to present questions properly here: we want questions to be clear and direct, and focused only on the question itself. It's good to try to find a solution to the problem first (and it's okay if you use ChatGPT to do that); but please *show* the result of your attempts *directly*, rather than talking about how you tried to figure it out. More importantly, please leave out all the greetings and formalities: this is **not a discussion forum**, and posts here are about **the code, not** you or anyone who answers.

Comment: Are you a normal user or how did you edit my text?

Comment: Every user on Stack Overflow can suggest edits for approval; everyone can edit their own posts; and users with 2000 or more reputation can participate in the approval process and also make edits directly. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges and https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation for details.